# DataSet not clearing old data using ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#

I'm using ExcelDataReader package to read an excel file but for some reason even after changing file name and using a different file it keeps outputting the old file's data even though it also has new file's data in it. I have tried dataset.clear and dispose methods but they aren't working.

```
 namespace excel
 {
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        ds1.Dispose();
        using (var stream = File.Open(@"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\excel\ctester.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {

            // Auto-detect format, supports:
            //  - Binary Excel files (2.0-2003 format; *.xls)
            //  - OpenXml Excel files (2007 format; *.xlsx)
            using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
            {

                // Choose one of either 1 or 2:

                // 1. Use the reader methods


                // 2. Use the AsDataSet extension method
                ds1.Dispose();
                ds1  = reader.AsDataSet();
                dt1 = ds1.Tables[0];

                // The result of each spreadsheet is in result.Tables
            }
        }

        foreach(DataColumn col in dt1.Columns)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row[col].ToString());
            }

        }
        Console.ReadKey();



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I don’t see an issue with the code.
2. Try save and closing the file.
3. Try setting the dataset to null
4. Are you getting the same data even in debugging?

Comment: Yes I'm in debugging mode and it's giving me the same result. When I put a break point and look at the dataset in dataset visualizer it still has the old dataset from previous file I opened with this program. I tried setting it equal to null and that didn't work either.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/wggix2f groupData is the old file and Sheet 1 is from this new file.